# histogram with straight density line

Tags: r, histogram

I want to plot a triangle over a histogram of lognormal data, so the top of the triangle coincides with the geometric mean. I tried this so far:

```
x <- rlnorm(100, log(20), log(2.5))
hist(x, xaxt='n', breaks=20, prob=T)
axis(side=1, at=seq(0,160, 5), labels=seq(0,160,5))
gm <- exp(mean(log(x)))
lines(density(x), col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some example code for adding a triangular distribution. The definitions of the upper and lower bounds of the triangular distribution can be changed based on your problem. The height of the triangle is scaled so that the total area is one.

```
x <- rlnorm(100, log(20), log(2.5))
hist(x, xaxt='n', breaks=20, prob=T)
axis(side=1, at=seq(0,160, 5), labels=seq(0,160,5))
gm <- exp(mean(log(x)))

# upper and lower bounds of triangle
lb <- 0
ub <- 85 

# peak y-value scaled so total area is one
lines(c(lb,gm,ub),c(0,2/(ub-lb),0)
      , col='blue'
      ,lwd=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Calvin Whealton, it looks great, thank you. I added a few changes to improve visibility:                                                                                                                                `x <- rlnorm(100, log(20), log(2.5))
hist(x, xaxt='n', breaks=20, prob=T)
axis(side=1, at=seq(0,250, 5), labels=seq(0,250,5))
gm <- exp(mean(log(x)))
lb <- 0
ub <- 225 
lines(c(lb,gm,ub),c(0,5/(ub-lb),0)
      , col='blue'
      ,lwd=2)`